# How to combine few bacis chars into one string in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

As a topic says. I try to combine few chars (from array) into one string.
i tried

```
char test[]={'A'};
char testt[]={'a'};
string testtt= test[0]+testt[0];
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `string testtt = string( test[0] ) + testt[0];`

Comment: At least one of the operands to [the `+` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) needs to be a string.

Comment: error.cpp:10:31: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
 string testtt = string( test[0] ) + testt[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char test[]={'A'};
char testt[]={'a'};
string testtt="";
testtt+=test[0];
testtt+=testt[0];
```

Comment: string testtt=""; not needed you can use string testtt;

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the constructor that takes char*, length.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(){


char test[]={'A'};
char testt[]={'a','w'};
std::string testtt= std::string(&test[0], 1) + std::string(&testt[1],1);/
std::cout<<testtt<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

or constructor that takes a range:

```
std::string testtt= std::string(&test[0], &test[1]) + std::string(&testt[0],&testt[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will do the trick ;)

```
#include <sstream>

string toStr(char* tab, int length)
{
    stringstream ss;
    for (int i=0 ; i<length; i++)
        ss << tab[i];
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look inside class string you'll find that it doesn't overload copy constructor to take one character parameter. 
you may think that you implement your own class containing a string object:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class MyStr
{
    public:
        MyStr(char c){ itsString = c;}
        string GetStr()const {return itsString;}

    private:
        string itsString;
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

char test[]={'A'};
char testt[]={'a'};
MyStr testtt = test[0] + testt[0];

cout << testtt.GetStr() << endl;


cout << endl << endl << endl;
return 0;
}
```

this program runs and the compiler never complains BUT the result won't be as you may think: it won't be "Aa" but just: 'ت'  because in fact the above statement: string testtt= test[0]+testt[0]; is equivalent to write: cout << (char)('A' + 'a');
which means summing two characters and the result is the integer ASCII value then this value will be converted back again to charater because you are really ivoking string(char); which will result to (charater of 162)